# Will this hashCode method overflow?

Tags: java, android, hashcode

I am writing an Android app that has an Achievement system, similar to the badges of Stack Overflow. I am also using Sugar ORM to store the Achievements' progress in the database. Here is the Achievement` class:

```
public class Achievement extends SugarRecord<Achievement>{
    @StringRes
    public int shortNameId;
    @StringRes
    public int descriptionId;
    public int progressNow;
    public int fullProgress; 
    //I am afraid that Sugar ORM will ignore private fields 
    //so I made them public. Please tell me if Sugar ORM does
    //not ignore those.
}
```

Now I want to override the `hashCode` method in the class. According to *Effective Java* 2nd Edition, I implemented it like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode () {
    int result = 17;
    result = result * 31 + shortNameId;
    result = result * 31 + descriptionId;
    result = result * 31 + fullProgress;
    return result;
}
```

Then I looked at the generated `R.java` to see what the string res ids are (I'm just curious). I realized that they are quite big numbers. In the `hashCode` method, I multiply `result` by 31, 3 times, which is already kinda big. Now I add the very large resource id to it. I am afraid that the resulting value would exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Can you tell me whether my `hashCode` method would overflow? If so how can I fix it?

Comment: Downvoter care to explain why?

Comment: Oh I know why downvote! I added [overflow] tag!

Comment: You should for the most part stay away from implementing the `hashCode() ` method yourself. It is much easier and save to let your IDE generate an appropriate `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation for you. Pretty much all IDE's can do that - even Eclipse. But to answer your question: integer overflows don't matter. `hashCode()` just tried to generate a unique number, overflows actually kinda help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Integer overflow doesn't produce an exception or other error, it just wraps around from `MIN_VALUE`. The only useful characteristic of `hashCode()` (besides the equality requirement) is that it be spread out somehow for differing values. Negative hash codes are fine. (In fact, `Integer#hashCode()` is just the `int` value.)